# Does a tent need special after-trip care when camping on and near ocean beaches?

Tags: camping, tents, gear-care, maintenance, beach

Does a tent need any special care after camping on or near ocean beaches? I know that salt can corrode metal (e.g. metal in the poles, stakes, zippers, etc.) and sand can mechanically abrade many parts of a tent. I don't know to what extent occasional use in those conditions will affect the longevity of a tent though.

Do I need to rinse everything out when I get done with such a trip, or is simply drying and brushing out the tent as usual sufficient to protect it from wearing out? Is there some other maintenance I should be considering following use in these conditions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Salt, sand and moisture are a bad combo for anything and everything. The salty sea air will wreak havoc on all your gear over time.

You won't have to worry about it too much just for occasional use, but I would recommend at least rinsing your tent with fresh water before storing it away.

There are [impregnatng agents and cleaners](http://www.ultramarxl.com/why-ultramar/) that you can buy that are designed to protect your tent materials as well as clean them so they don't deteriorate. They're used mostly on sails and canvas tents, but you can can also get some for more modern tent materials.

I would say that there's no such thing as caring too much for your gear, it's always a good practice to put things a away nice and clean after a trip. Use your judgement when inspecting your gear after a trip, if it looks, smells or feels like it could use a cleaning, then you should probably give it some TLC. If you do get some products to help care for your tent materials, make sure you follow the cleaning schedule recommendations for those products.